# How to reverse to a View class?

Tags: python, django

This is my views.py file. I want to reverse into PollView in the end of vote function but I am getting an error.

ERROR:
[image]

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, reverse, redirect
from django.views import View
from .models import Question, Choice


# Create your views here.
class PollView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        questions = Question.objects.all()

        return render(request, "app/poll.html", {'questions': questions})


def vote(request, pk):
    choice = Choice.objects.get(pk=pk)
    choice.votes += 1
    choice.save()
    return reverse('poll:index')
```

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import PollView, vote

app_name = 'poll'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PollView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('vote/<int:pk>', vote)
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need `redirect` not `reverse`. `reverse` will return the url that you want and you will need to `redirect` to that view/url.

```py
def vote(request, pk):
    choice = Choice.objects.get(pk=pk)
    choice.votes += 1
    choice.save()
    return redirect(reverse('poll:index'))
```